# Batch to empty hosts file and add multiple lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, hosts

I found about half a dozen ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773383/windows-batch-to-add-a-record-to-hosts-file), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666740/windows-batch-how-to-add-host-entries?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489955/windows-batch-to-add-replace-entry-in-hosts-file) etc.) questions about how to add lines to the Windows hosts file but none of them are easy to maintain if you want to frequently update multiple lines with a single batch file in which you can just replace the old lines with your new ones as a block and delete everything else inside the hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 example1.com
127.0.0.1 example2.com
127.0.0.1 example3.com
127.0.0.1 example4.com
127.0.0.1 example5.com
```

I was hoping you guys can tell me what I missed, where to look or maybe even give me an example. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your description is insufficient. What you mean by 'previously added'? Added by last update, added ever before?

Comment: I mean completely remove all entries (inclusive #). Just everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you know what you are doing:
to rewrite the whole hosts file with new contents simply:

```
@Echo off
Set "Hosts=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
Copy "%Hosts%" "%Hosts%.bak"
( Echo 127.0.0.1 example1.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example2.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example3.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example4.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example5.com
) > "%Hosts%"
```

This batch will append to the original hosts file and save a copy with appended date&time `hosts_yyyyMMddhhmmss.bak` to the current users `Documents` folder which should be no problem.

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set "Bak=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Hosts_%%A.bak"

Set "Hosts=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
Copy /Y "%Hosts%" "%Bak%"

( Echo 127.0.0.1 example1.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example2.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example3.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example4.com
  Echo 127.0.0.1 example5.com
) >> "%Hosts%"
```

Comment: Could you post a version of the batch to just add lines without removing existing? :)

Comment: Well the second one preserves existing entries but removes comments per your request. Do you want to create entries other than redirections to localhost?

Comment: The second script doesn't work. There is no hosts file anymore, only "hosts.new".

Comment: The batch works locally but my AntiVirus keeps me from changing the original path what I'm not going to disable for a test.

Comment: But why doesn't it work on my system? I use Windows Defender and there was no notification.

Comment: To append the entries to the original host file change the first batch to have two redirection symbols in the last line `) >> "%Hosts%"`

Comment: Yes, also I needed to remove "Move /Y "%Hosts%" "%Hosts%.bak"" and now it works but I'd much rather keep a backup...

Comment: Then choose a different **save** location ;-)

Comment: Why doesn't it work like the first one? Why was it necessary to remove the line? :/

Comment: The host file can be used maliciously redirecting known urls to different ones - so editing should IMO be limited/supervised.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand. I want a backup of the hosts file "hosts.bak" like the first script did. The "second" script is just like the first one except with " ) >> "%Hosts%" " as last line so why is it not possible to backup a copy of the hosts file just like the first script did?

Comment: See changed second batch.

Comment: It works but still no backup. Not in Documents, not in hosts file folder. :( And if it works: So it's really not possible to put the backup in the same directory as the hosts file?

Comment: Sorry my fault changed the erroneous move to a copy.

Comment: Sorry to say but there is still no backup. :(

Comment: Please change the echo to on and run the batch in an open cmd window to see whats happening. Here it works fine (aside from my AV not allowing to change the original hosts file)

Comment: It works! It didn't work because my "Documents" folder is in "D:\Documents". After that I've tried change the backup path to "%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" but that didn't work. I really want to save the backup just as "hosts.bak" inside the hosts folder, no date in the name, no multiple backups. Just one simple "hosts.bak" file. Is that possible?

Comment: But you said the original first version doesn't work, try it agagin with echo on to see whats the problem. But you should now have the knowledge to try on your own ;.)

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very very much! I appreciate your time!

Comment: One little question: How can I just empty the whole hosts file? I removed all the lines and tried " ) > "%Hosts%" " but nothing changes.

Comment: `Type NUL >"%Hosts%"` will reset the file to zero length

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! :D

Comment: Sorry, another question: Is it possible to "echo" all lines by default so that you can just copy & paste the updated hosts lines without the "echo"s in every line?

Comment: If you have new entries in a textfile you can `Type "yourfile.txt" >>"%Hosts%"` But 25 comments are much to much. Put new questions into [new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)